# AngularJS trouble adding page titles

Tags: html, angularjs, uiview, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-template

I am writing a web app using AngularJS. It is not a single page application but all my codes are in one file- index.ejs.

So my set up for index.ejs roughly looks like this:

```
<head>
   <title> Main page </title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
       <ui-view></ui-view>
     </div>
   </div>

   <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "/main.html">
   .....
   </script>

   <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "/addStuff.html">
   .....
   </script>

   <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "/searchStuff.html">
   .....
   </script>

   <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "/about.html">
   .....
   </script>
</body>
```

I have a title for the main page on top of index.ejs. I would also like to have seperate titles for each page so when they are opened in a new tab, I know which one is which. I have tried doing:

```
<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "/addStuff.html">
    <head>
        <title> Add Stuff </title>
    </head>
    .....
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ui-router. In which case you can add a top level controller on the `body` or `html` element, for example `<html ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">`

And add a '$stateChangeSuccess' listener whenever a new route is loaded...

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (angular.isDefined(toState.data.pageTitle)) {
            $scope.pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle;
        }
    });
})
```

Then in the route definition you can add a property called `data.pageTitle`

```
    $stateProvider.state( 'profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'profile/profile.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ 
           pageTitle: 'Profile' 
        }
    })
```

Then in your main index.html file, you can bind the `pageTitle` attribute:

```
    <title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>
```

Comment: Cool!  I learned that trick from http://joshdmiller.github.io/ng-boilerplate/#/home

Answer (score 0):

The most important part is the you move the directive `ng-app` on the `<html>` tag if it's not already in there.

Thus all the html page is covered by angular.

Eg:

```
<html ng-app="app">

  ...

</html>
```

Then it's really your choice.
You can use a custom directive to wrap the title, generate a service or just use the `{{ }}` syntax.